# /dev/fb0 not working in Android emulator with Linux rootfs

Tags: android

I'm running Debian amd64 root fs in Android emulator with default kernel from Android 9.
After starting I have a device

```
ls -la /dev/fb0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 29, 0 Aug 27 09:17 /dev/fb0

fbset -s -fb /dev/fb0
mode "1280x720"
    geometry 1280 720 1280 720 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/0.8/8.8/16.0/0
end mode
```

When executing the command

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0
cat: write error: No space left on device
```

nothing appears on the display of the emulator.

Nothing happens when starting the X server

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Debian
Current Operating System: Linux (none) 4.4.124+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 18 17:10:07 UTC 2018 x86_64
Kernel command line: nopti no_timer_check clocksource=pit no-kvmclock console=ttyS0,38400 cma=272M@0-4G ndns=2 mac80211_hwsim.radios=2 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 skip_initramfs rootwait ro init=/init root=/dev/vda1 loop.max_part=7 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 printk.devkmsg=on qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR31X2_X10X0 qemu.gles=1 qemu.screen_settings =2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.vsync=60 qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800 qemu.opengles.version=196608 qemu.uirenderer=skiagl qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=576m qemu.camera_hq_edge_processing=0 androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/ qemu.wifi=1 android.qemud=1 qemu.avd_name=TINYSYS ndns=2 mac80211_hwsim.mac_prefix=5554
Build Date: 16 December 2021 05:08:23PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.11-1+deb11u1 (https://www.debian.org/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Aug 27 09:25:14 2022
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

**[ 16.291788] x86/PAT: Xorg:2485 map pfn RAM range req uncached-minus for [mem 0xaec00000-0xaf307fff], got write-back**

According to the X server logs, it works in framebuffer mode.

Can you advise me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following way to run the emulator:

```
emulator -avd TINYSYS -shell -qemu -usb -device usb-tablet -device virtio-vga,edid=on,xres=720,yres=1280 -kernel /home/root/emulator/rootfs/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.302-tiny \
-append 'selinux=0 no_timer_check clocksource=pit no-kvmclock console=0 cma=272M@0-4G mac80211_hwsim.radios=2 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 skip_initramfs rootwait ro init=/sbin/init root=/dev/vdf2 .. .
```

/dev/vdf is the sdcard

Kernel rebuilt with virtio DRM support.

:(( But fb still not working.